# SSIS Deploy Error

Tags: ssis, integration

I made a package in SSIS that convert from a DBF file to the SQL server.
Well in visual studio it works perfectly, but after i deployed my project in sql server it doesn't work.
See the images:[image]

Someone know what is wrong?

tks for the attention

Answer (score 2):

When you deploy to your SQL Server catalog ensure you have the appropriate drivers installed. If you need the access drivers that include the office drivers to read excel files you can install them from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

If you are using a 64bit installation of SQL Server you will need the 64 bit driver.

If you are doing tests in your local machine and have both Visual Studio (running in 32 bits) and SQL Server (running in 64 bits), instead of removing the 32 bit driver, you may want to change your package properties after deployment and force the 32 bit mode execution. See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/run-integration-services-ssis-packages?view=sql-server-ver15#advanced

Hope this helps.